# Moving website creating using foundation 5 to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I have just recently created my website using the normal foundation frame work which consists of as you would normally see in frameworks HTML5,CSS, JS etc. I was trying to have a look at a few posts on stack overflow regarding moving a normal website to WordPress. I have seen that the structure of the files on WordPress themes is completely different. Any way of going through this approach . I don't want to be going the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this wordpress theme http://foundationpress.olefredrik.com/ which already supports foundation 5.

Comment: I have got that theme. I am talking about converting my own website which is already made on to wordpress. It has been used using the normal foundation. Not the wordpress foundation @emeraldjava

Comment: post the link to your current site. I'd suspect that your static html pages will become posts/pages in wordpress, and then any custom css/js will be merged into the wordpress theme config. TBH - this is a vague question.

Comment: my website link is www.f-sharpmedia.com 

I just want to be able to manage everything easily using Wordpress. @emeraldjava

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, but you are going to have to spend some time figuring out how WordPress works. What you are asking is similar to what I am working on right now. The basic idea is to turn your website into a WordPress theme.

If you haven't done it, the first thing you will need to do is set up WordPress locally on your computer. You then need to create a directory in the `wp-content/themes` directory and copy your current website to it. This will give you the structure `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/`. ('your-theme-name' is whatever you want to call your theme.)

To get WordPress to recognize your theme you need to create a `style.css` file in the root of the directory that has at minimum this in its header:

```
/*
Theme Name: my theme name
*/
```

You then need to rename your `index.html` file to `index.php`. You should now be able to go the admin page of your WordPress installation and see your-theme-name show up as a possible selection. Select it and you should see an unstyled version of your `index.php` page.

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321) is a good tutorial on the proper way to include css and javascript in your theme.

[Here](http://garethcooper.com/2014/01/zurb-foundation-5-and-wordpress-menus/) is a tutorial on how to get WordPress to generate menus with a structure that Foundation expects.

To be able to display pages other than `index.php` and use WordPress as a content management system for your site, you'll have to learn about the WordPress loop (search the codex) and how WordPress deals with urls (search stackoverflow for 'how does WordPress internal url rewrite work'.)

To really figure this out it's worth going through the default themes supplied with the WordPress installation and any themes you can find that are based on Foundation.

Comment: There is a book called 'The Web Designer's Guide to WordPress' that outlines this kind of approach.

Comment: If you plan to make more than one site with Foundation/WordPress you might find that extending a Foundation base theme with your own child theme is a better approach.